# mysql 5.6.29 select as subquery access violation 1064

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm running a query inside laravel 5.4 that looks like this:

```
    ->orderBy("         
        select ifnull(distance, 10) from location_distances as ld where ld.location1 = '".Auth::user()->location."' and ld.location2=(select ifnull(location,'') from users as usl where usl.id=statuses.user.id)", "desc")
```

Im getting the error:

```
    SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Syntax error next to 'as `ld where ld.location1 = 'New york' and ld.location2=(select ifnull(locatio' in line 1
```

Appearently I cannot use select as inside a subquery, the problem is, this query works fine in phpmyadmin

Can you please help me out?

Thank you

Comment: did you try using orderByRaw? ->orderByRaw("select ifnull(distance, 10) from location_distances as ld where ld.location1 = '".Auth::user()->location."' and ld.location2=(select ifnull(location,'') from users as usl where usl.id=statuses.user.id) desc")

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes I tried, but then my query returns nothing

Comment: Can you post complete Query Builder code and query you run in phpmyadmin

Comment: $statuses= Status::notReply()->orderByRaw("(
select ifnull(distance, 10) from location_distances as ld where ld.location1 = '".Auth::user()->location."' and ld.location2=(select ifnull(location,'') from users as usl where usl.id=statuses.user_id))", "desc");
and in the query, I just replace varuables with values

Comment: I suggest you dump SQL generated by query builder. Just output query with ->toSql(), then see if it's generated ok